# XMLPullParser parsing from internet in asynctask error in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-asynctask, xmlpullparser

I'm developing an application on the Android system which involves parsing some xml stuff. The problem is that the program is crashing and I've haven't found out the problem. I have an Activity which has a private class which extends asynctask. This is the code:

```
URL url = new URL(XML_INIT_ADRESS);
XmlPullParser xpp =  XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), null);

int pullParserState = xpp.getEventType();

while (pullParserState != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
    if (xpp.getName().equals("signupclients") && pullParserState == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){ //Error!!!               
        while(!xpp.getName().equals("signupclients") && pullParserState != XmlPullParser.END_TAG){
            if (xpp.getName().equals("client")) {
                clientNames.add(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));
            }
            pullParserState = xpp.next();
        }
        pullParserState = xpp.next();
    }
}
```

As you can see I've commented on the first if-statement that if you comment away that and the code its containing the code will work. I could add that it's in Eclipse and I catch all errors.

```
String XML_INIT_ADRESS = "http://www.johanstenberg.se/tests/app/start.xml"
```

It should be a valid XML-document. Please help because I'm clueless but I want to see it work with the XMLPullParser. I call the asynctask which in the onCreate() method like this:

```
new UpdateDatabase().execute();
```

Where UpdateDatabase is the name of the private class extending Asynctask.

Thanks in advance!

Logcat:

```
12-05 18:38:43.664: W/KeyCharacterMap(525): No keyboard for id 0
12-05 18:38:43.664: W/KeyCharacterMap(525): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
12-05 18:38:44.854: I/AndroidRuntime(525): AndroidRuntime onExit calling exit(0)
12-05 18:38:45.154: D/dalvikvm(535): GC freed 750 objects / 54888 bytes in 51ms
12-05 18:38:45.584: W/dalvikvm(535): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
12-05 18:38:45.594: E/AndroidRuntime(535): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #1 exiting due to uncaught exception
12-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
1    2-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
12-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
12-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
12-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at com.discountapp.johanaugust.UpdatingDB$UpdateDatabase.doInBackground(UpdatingDB.java:119)
12-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at com.discountapp.johanaugust.UpdatingDB$UpdateDatabase.doInBackground(UpdatingDB.java:1)
12-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  ... 4 more
12-05 18:38:45.654: I/dalvikvm(535): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
12-05 18:38:45.654: E/dalvikvm(535): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: Could you enquire the logcat traces and share to see what happens?

Comment: This gives a good clue:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 12-05 18:38:45.604: E/AndroidRuntime(535): at com.discountapp.johanaugust.UpdatingDB$UpdateDatabase.doInBackground(UpdatingDB.java:119).  Which line is 119 in UpdatingDB.java?

Comment: if(xpp.getName().equals("signupclients")){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting an exception from this line:

```
if(xpp.getName().equals("signupclients") && pullParserState == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
```

Then my best guess is that **xpp.getName() is returning null**, and you are trying to invoke `.equals()` from that null reference.

You should be checking the **eventType** from your **XmlPullParser** before trying to do something with it.  Take a look at this snippet from the [JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html):

```
         int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
         while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
          if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
              System.out.println("Start document");
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
              System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
              System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
              System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
          }
          eventType = xpp.next();
         }
```

Its hard to give a more definitive answer without more details (like a stack trace).

Comment: Thats my conclusion aswell, that xpp.getName() is null, but why is it that? If you look at my code I shouldn't have a error there. The xml resource (check the link) should be ok so why isnt it working?

Comment: Yeah its null I just did a if-statement which SYstem.exit(0); so. But why :(?

Comment: It will be null if you are not on one of these events: START_TAG, END_TAG, or ENTITY_REF.  That's why you should loop through all of the events and process them based on their type.

Comment: The first event you get is probably PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION because your XML doc starts with: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>.  Since that is not one of the events I listed above, it will return null if you call getName().

Comment: That was the issue, that I didn't xpp.next() enough so it gave a nullpointerexception. Thanks man!